# Filezilla Server on IIS 7.5 on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: iis-7.5, ftp

We are developers (meaning: not sysadmins who know what they do), and we use a Windows Virtual Server as a staging server.

Setting up FTP accounts on IIS 7.5, while possible, is not as simple and straightforward as using Filezilla Server (and it has ugly user names), so we'd like to know:

Is there any reason we should *not* use Filezilla Server instead of the build-in FTP server on a not-so-critical staging server?

Would it be safe enough for a production server as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no reason it couldn't work out fine, though I use the FTP-SSL functionality in IIS FTP7.5 myself.

But I would want someone experienced with Filezilla server to, at very minimum, examine the initial configuration you plan to use. And keep in mind that you would need to keep FZ Server updated separately.

Comment: The additional need to update is certainly an issue. Thanks Andrew.